# Application Insights JS trackException shows "Failed method: 'Unkown'"

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-application-insights

I'm experimenting with AppInsights and use the following code:
(fetch fails with a 500 reply)

```
private callMethod(): void {
  this._callMethodInternal();
}

private async _callMethodInternal(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await fetch("https://localhost:44369/api/values", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "text/json"
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    AppInsights.trackException(err);

    throw err;
  }
}
```

The exception is shown in Application Insights, but the "Failed method" property shows "Unknown" as value.
Is there a way to show the correct method name?

Thanks

(https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/680)

Answer (score 1):

you are not passing proper params. Follwoing is the updated method

```
trackException(exception: Error, handledAt?: string, properties?: {[string]:string}, measurements?: {[string]:number}, severityLevel?: AI.SeverityLevel)
```

For reference, check following link
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md

Comment: what params would then be needed to resolve the Method: Unknown issue?

Answer (score 1):

The type of object expected by `trackException` is `IExceptionTelemtry` rather than a native `Error` object. In other words, you can't pass the caught error directly to `trackException`.

The [API reference](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md) outlines all of the `IExceptionTelemtry` properties, but the most important is the `exception` property, as it is required.

Example:

```js
try {
  // logic that throws
} catch (error) {
  AppInsights.trackException({ exception: error });
}
```